# Drawing in cocoa swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've been trying to draw a simple line in a cocoa application using swift, however I fail to fully understand how to use the CGContext class.

I've created this class:

```
import Cocoa
class Drawing: NSView {
override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

    let context = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext;

    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

  }
}
```

and used it in the main window like so

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dr = Drawing()
    self.view.addSubview(dr)
    dr.drawRect(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

but it didn't do a thing

Comment: Try adding the subview after calling `drawRect()` instead

Comment: Why not UIView instead of NSView subclassing?

Comment: Because it's a Cocoa (MacOS) not UIKit (iOS) application.

Comment: Are you drawing on a white background, because you are setting the color to white.

Comment: You also don't need to explicitly call `drawRect` it will get automatically drawn as part of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialise your `Drawing` view with a frame otherwise the system won't know where to draw it, like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dr = Drawing(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    self.view.addSubview(dr)
}
```

Also as David said, you do not need to call `drawRect` yourself as it is automatically called by the system.

Comment: More to the point, you *should* not call `drawRect()` yourself. The system sets up the graphics context for your view before it calls that method. When you call it yourself, you're not doing the same setup, so the graphics context will be incorrect and may not even exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents for swift 5.x Xcode 10:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else{
        return
    }

    context.beginPath()
    context.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    context.addLine(to: CGPoint( x: 100, y: 100))
    context.setStrokeColor(CGColor( red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
    context.setLineWidth(5.0)
    context.strokePath()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a view or use CoreGraphics instructions.
Simply do like this:   ( EDIT: I added update exemple code )

```
class View: NSView {
    
    var p1: NSPoint = .zero { 
        didSet { needsDisplay = true }
    }
    
    var p2: NSPoint = NSPoint(x: 100, y: 100) {
        didSet { needsDisplay = true }
    }

    // Returns the rect using the two points
    var rect: NSRect {
        NSRect(x: p1.x, y: p1.y,
               width: p2.x - p1.x, height: p2.y - p1.y)
    }
    
    // Draw a rectangle and its diagonal

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        // Draw rect 
        
        let rect = self.rect        
        NSColor.red.setFill()
        NSColor.black.setStroke()
        rect.fill()
        rect.stroke()

        // Draw line

        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.move(to: p1)
        path.line(to: p2)
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to call** `myView.needsDisplay = true` **to update content**

From there, check auto completion to discover Cocoa drawing functions to draw paths, ovals, rounded rects. Cheers :)